# Rails refactoring long where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't like passing multiple repeating arguments, it looks a bit ugly.
how can I refactor the following code?

```
 prev_month_start = Date.today.prev_month.beginning_of_month
 prev_month_end = Date.today.prev_month.end_of_month
    
 contacts = contacts.where('
   persons.actual_delivery_date >= ? AND persons.actual_delivery_date <= ? OR 
   persons.expected_shipment_date >= ? AND persons.expected_shipment_date <= ?', 
   prev_month_start, prev_month_end, 
   prev_month_start, prev_month_end)
```

Comment: What's the end goal of refactoring here? There are a lot of ways to think about refactoring this, but I'd probably start w/ meaningful scopes (e.g., `delivered_last_month` and `shipment_expected_last_month` etc).

Comment: How is `contacts` composed? Is `Person` the model that produces the `contacts` variable? Like in `contacts = Person.all`. Or is the `persons` table a joint table? eg. `contracts = Contract.all.joins(:person)`. Could you provide us with a bit more context? How does the `persons` table relate to the `contacts` scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a date range ([`all_month`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_month)) in cases like these combined with a [`or` condition](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions):

```
prev_month = Date.today.prev_month.all_month
contacts = contacts
  .where(persons: { actual_delivery_date: prev_month })
  .or(contacts.where(persons: { expected_shipment_date: prev_month }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with ActiveRecord 5 and above:

```
contacts.where(actual_delivery_date: prev_month_start..prev_month_end).or(expected_shipment_date: prev_month_start..prev_month_end)
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions

edited based on comments

Comment: Rails 5 supports `or` so can do something like this:  contacts.where(actual_delivery_date: prev_month_start..prev_month_end).or(expected_shipment_date: prev_month_start..prev_month_end)